# How many ordered sets there are with k elements (with limitation )

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many ordered sets there are with k elements such that every element is a subset of $[n]$. so that $\{T_1,T_2,T_3, \dots,T_k\} \subseteq [n]^k$ and $T_1 \cap T_2 \cap \dots \cap T_k= \emptyset$ and $T_1 \cup T_2 \cup \dots \cup T_k =[n]$.

$[n]=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, you should explain what you know, show what you have attempted, and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  Please [edit] your question accordingly.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Am I understanding it correctly that you're looking for a partition of $[n]$ into $k$ sets wich $k$ elements each?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right then this number is exactly the number of all $k$-colorings of the set $[n]$, that is maps from $[n]$ to $[k]$, which is, clearly $k^n$.

Answer (score 0):

The Stirling numbers $S(n, k)$ count the number of ways to partition $[n]$ into $k$ nonempty subsets. Since the $T_i$ are ordered, for each partition $\{T_1, \cdots, T_k\}$ you can permute these $k$ subsets in $k!$ ways, giving $k!S(n, k)$ ordered partitions. If the $T_i$ are allowed to be empty then you should sum $k!S(n, j)$ for $j = 1, \cdots, k$.